# Implementing one dimensional gsl integration in C++ with parameters as border of integration

Tags: c++, gsl, numerical-integration

I'd like to perform the following one dimensional integration in C++ using gsl,

`I(x) = int_{x/4}^1 dy y^{3/2+a} (1-y)^{1/2} exp(1.13*sqrt(log(4y/x))),` where `a` and `x` are treated as constants of the integration and I would like to be able to perform the integration for `x` sampled in the interval `0.000001<x<0.001` for a fixed `a` provided by the user.

Here is my attempt:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

double integrand(double y, void * params) {
double a = *(double *) params;
double x = *(double *) params; 

double intg = pow(y,3e0/2e0+a)*pow(1-y,1e0/2e0)*exp(1.13*sqrt(log(4*y/x)));

return intg;

}

double integral(double a) {

gsl_integration_workspace * w
= gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);
gsl_function F;
F.function = &integrand;                 
F.params = &a;
double result, error;

for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    double x = (0.001-0.000001)*i/100 + 0.000001;


gsl_integration_qags (&F, x/4, 1e0, 0, 1e-7, 1000,
                      w, &result, &error);

}
 gsl_integration_workspace_free (w); // Free memory

return result;
}




int main(){
std::cout << "x" << x << "result "<< integral(-0.046)<<std::endl;

 }
```

The problem I am having is how to pass the value of `x` given by the for loop to the integrand?  At the moment, the code returns `nan` because I am not passing `x` to the integrand, only to the x dependence in the lower integration boundary.  Still a newbie in C++ so apologies in advance for possible simplicity of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the x indicated in the lower limit of integration ("x/4" expression) is the same as the x participating in the formula of the integrand, then the solution is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//create a structure for the parameters of the integral function: 

struct params 
{
    double a;
    double x;
};

//create an integration function for the x variable: 
//let all INTERNAL parameters have a prefix "_" in the name:   

double integrand(double y, void * params_from_above)
{
    //declare our structure for parameters and be sure to do type casting, 
    //and initialize the parameter values passed from above:
    params& _inner_params = *(params*)params_from_above;
    
    //we calculate the value of the integrand using the passed parameter values:
    double _intg = pow(y, 1.5 + _inner_params.a) * pow(1.0 - y, 0.5) * exp(1.13 * sqrt(log(4.0 * y/_inner_params.x)));

    return _intg;
}


double integral(double a)
{
    double result, error;
    
    //declare a structure for storing and passing "a" and "x" parameters:
    params custom_params;
    //create integration workspace:
    gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);
    
    //declare and initialize gsl callback function for integrand:
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &integrand;
    
    //declare and initialize gsl params structure:
    //(so far only for the value of "a" parameter)
    F.params = &custom_params;    
    custom_params.a = a;

    //start the main cycle of calculations:    
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //compute x parameter value:
        double _x = (0.001-0.000001)*i/100 + 0.000001;
        //save the value of the X parameter for sending to the integrand:
        custom_params.x = _x;
        
        //compute the integral for current "x"/4 parameter value:
        gsl_integration_qags (&F, _x/4.0, 1.0, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);
        
        //output integral value:
        printf("res = %f\n", result);
        //delay: press any key for continue: 
        system("pause");

    }
    gsl_integration_workspace_free (w); // Free memory

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //here you are mistaken, since only the last value is displayed...
    //but I left your expression for the sake of calling an integral function:
    std::cout << "result "<< integral(-0.046) << std::endl; 
}
```

And I get the following output for the first five "x" parameter values:

```
C:\Users\...\CLionProjects\gsl_test\cmake-build-debug\gsl_test.exe
res = 15.226887
Press any key to continue . . .

res = 10.523077
Press any key to continue . . .

res = 9.467232
Press any key to continue . . .

res = 8.870463
Press any key to continue . . .

res = 8.459477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: thank you very much, that does it. Could you explain what  the code snippet ‘params& _inner_params = *(params*)params_from_above;’ means? I understand some casting is done because the internal variable is a pointer to a type void and the params members are type double? But I would like to understand this snippet piece by piece. Thank you very much.

Comment: `params& _inner_params = *(params*)params_from_above`; on left: that means, what we create reference on the `params` type (reference on structure type). On right: we convert types explicitly: convert `void*` type to `params*` (pointers type to pointers type!) and we take values from the pointer! This is a very simple expression, read it from right to left: take `void` pointer, convert to `params` pointer, then take value from this pointer and initialize the reference with this value.

Comment: Thank you. So to check my understanding: `params_from_above` is a pointer of type `void`, so `*(params*)params_from_above` casts `params_from_above` as a pointer of type `params`. Then the inner variable `_inner_params` is initialised with the VALUE which this pointer is pointing to, by means of the `&`. Is that the correct meaning?

Comment: Yes, almost right, but it's easier :)
`_inner_params` -- it's just a _reference_, that is, an alias, _pseudonym_ for bulky construction `*(params*)params_from_above`. Reference using instead `*(params*)params_from_above` because reference -- easier, shorter and safer. Once again - we declare `_inner_params` as a structure type variable and immediately initialize by taking the VALUE from the pointer (we take the VALUE using the leftmost `*` into `*(params*)params_from_above` expression).
P.S.: if my version of the code helped you, please mark it as a solution :)

Comment: thank you very much, that makes more sense indeed. +1 and accepted